# large scale online data gathering

Tags: web-applications, asp.net-web-api

I am an absolute beginner to developing web applications, so if I ask an elementary question or posting in the wrong place, please say so kindly!

I would like to develop a Web application (that is accessed over the Web) with the general aim of large scale online data gathering about peoples' physical attributes, such as weight or height measurements.

This has to be interactive, so that (for example) something like a message appears on the screen, then the user enters something, and then we obtain that input, so we can process the gathered data, etc...

For such a general description task, where should I start?

What kind of Web application / API should I look into?

Thanks in advance,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to collect the data from the users' input, you need to have the webpage post the information back to the server. There, you need to use a server-side technology that will handle the posted data and store them to a store (e.g. SQL database).

There are a lot of technologies you can use for this purpose so let's look at some and figure out where and how they can be used for your project:

1. Web page content and styling: HTML, CSS
2. Client-side interaction logic: Javascript
3. Server-side logic: ASP.NET (MVC or WebForms or even just Web Api) or PHP or Ruby etc.
4. Data storage: MySQL or MS SQL Server or some sort of NoSQL database (e.g. MongoDB) etc.

Being an absolute beginner, you should start by figuring out how these layers could be combined to create a web application and then go on and choose the ones you feel more suited to your project and that are more compatible together.

There are plenty of resources online, for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/) are some tutorials for beginners from w3Schools